# Map group by several values in Elixir

Tags: elixir

So I have this Map

```
    map = [
             %{id: 2, brand: "TUTU", reference: "1234"}, 
             %{id: 2, brand: "TUTU", reference: "4567"}, 
             %{id: 3, brand: "TOTO", reference: "789456"}
    ]
```

And I would like do group it by ID to get something like this :

```
    [
        %{
            id: 2,
            brand: "TUTU",
            reference: [
                 "1234",
                 "5845"
              ]
        },
        %{
             id: 3,
             brand: "TOTO",
             reference: [
                  "4587"
             ]
        }
    ]
```

I tried to use `Enum.group_by` like this

```
map
|> Enum.group_by(fn entry -> entry.brand end)
```

But the result looked like this :

```
    %{
      "TOTO" => [%{brand: "TOTO", id: 3, reference: "789456"}],
      "TUTU" => [
        %{brand: "TUTU", id: 2, reference: "1234"},
        %{brand: "TUTU", id: 2, reference: "4567"}
      ]
    }
```

I feel like I am close to the solution but I dont know how I can regroup my info into lists instead of taking using the keys as indexes....

Sorry I am not very clear I just don't know how to describe my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to be very fancy with detecting the keys that don't need to be grouped by and can just list them up-front, then a nested `Enum.map` like this will do what you want:

```
data = [
  %{id: 2, brand: "TUTU", reference: "1234"},
  %{id: 2, brand: "TUTU", reference: "4567"},
  %{id: 2, brand: "TOTO", reference: "4567"},
  %{id: 3, brand: "TOTO", reference: "789456"}
]

keys_to_group_by = [:id, :brand]
keys_to_list = [:reference]

data
|> Enum.group_by(&Map.take(&1, keys_to_group_by))
|> Enum.map(fn {key, values} ->
  keys_to_list
  |> Enum.map(fn key_to_list ->
    {key_to_list, Enum.map(values, & &1[key_to_list])}
  end)
  |> Enum.into(key)
end)
```

Note the `|> Enum.group_by(&Map.take(&1, keys_to_group_by))` - this is the part that groups by many keys, so that `%{id: 2, brand: "TOTO"}` and `%{id: 2, brand: "TUTU"}` end up in different buckets.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility would be to [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) directly into the desired structure with [`Kernel.update_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html?#update_in/3):

```rb
data
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn %{id: id, brand: brand, reference: ref}, acc ->  
  update_in(acc, [{id, brand}], fn
    nil -> %{id: id, brand: brand, reference: [ref]}
    refs -> %{refs | reference: [ref | refs.reference]}
  end)
end)
|> Map.values()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at [Enum.reduce/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) and [Map.update/4](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#update/4) instead of a simple `Enum.group_by/2` to save you from having to then map the grouped entries into only references.

```
map
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, &group_by_brand/2)
|> Enum.map(&to_map/1)

...

defp group_by_brand(entry, acc) do
  Map.update(acc, {entry.id, entry.brand}, [entry.reference], &[entry.reference | &1])
end

defp to_map({{id, brand}, references}) do
  %{id: id, brand: brand, references: references}
end
```